# MapView touch location different between phone, tablet and PC for same point on map

Tags: android, google-maps, overlay, android-mapview

I am developing an app where I display a MapView on a tablet screen, touch a particular location, overlay a marker at the location, and save the GeoPoint of the location touched via the onTap() event.  I know the screen point being touched very precisely from using the Developer's setting which displays screen touch location.  Unfortunately, the points saved all appear to be shifted to the east relative to what I'm considering my "truth measurement", i.e. clicking the same points in Google Maps on a Windows PC and recording those coordinates.

My app can DISPLAY markers in the exact location I get from the querying points on the PC, it just cannot GET the same coordinates by querying from the tablet.  Could I have inadvertently shifted the overlay which reads clicks, relative to the map itself?  Very frustrating, but my app requires consistency.

Is there a reason why getting a location from a PC screen could be more accurate than the corresponding operation on a tablet or phone?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't post the code, it's difficult to guess what is going wrong ...

Shifted marker problems are in most cases related to wrongly set (or missing) marker bounds.

Regards.